# Is 'arcanus scintilla vitae' gramatically correct?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin, translation-check

I'm trying to figure out how to put together "the mysterious spark of life" in Latin, though the cases are a tad confusing. Doing some searching and translating has led me to those 3 words, though I'm not sure.

Also, *mysticum essentia vitae* is a choice, though unsure on that too: "the mystical essence of life"?

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not grammatically correct. Since *scintilla* is feminine (and since *arcanus, -a, -um* is one of those adjectives that have special endings in the feminine gender), it should be ***arcana scintilla vitae***.

The same applies to your second phrase; it should be ***mystica essentia vitae***.

Other than that, both suggestions look quite good to me.

I googled a bit, and *scintilla vitae* is clearly a time-honoured phrase, although it is not clear to me how old it really is. It is, however,  reminiscent of the *scintilla animae* (spark of the soul) of the late medieval German mystic [Meister Eckhart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meister_Eckhart). *Essentia vitae*, on the other hand, seems to be an old (18th, 19th century) pharmaceutical term for certain mixtures; I would not let that deter me, though: *essentia* clearly means "essence" in the philosophical sense first, and in the, shall we say, snake-oil sense last.

Comment: Thank you again, Sebastian.